# Kendo hierarchy grid error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Im using three grids in one by using hierarchy grids. The problem is that it kind of freaks out sometimes without throwing any error at all.

this is what is looks like:

[image]

If i press the first row in the second grid:

[image]

it then looks like this when it should look more like this:
[image]

Anyone knows why i get this "error" or what ever it is.

This might happen when the first row is expanded and the grid that opens up doesn't contain any rows. But that is also a weird case because it should be showing an empty grid in that case.

Comment: Please provide Code snip to check the error

Answer (score 1):

use below link

http://jsfiddle.net/gr2t3/6/

```
      If any changes regarding this code compare to your code then share the link or code..
```